# how to reposition JButton on resizing the window

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have kept a JButton in the bottom middle part of my JFrame. Now whenever I resize the window the JButton should be repositioned (in the new centre) depending on new resized window. Can anyone tell me how to accomplish this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please post some code snippets, otherwise it will be hard to help you!

Comment: @Nilesh - I think what timmyd is trying to say is that, if you accepted more answers (when they solved your problem), more people may be willing to help you on your future questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Components in Swing are rendered according to the frame's layout manager. The default layout manager is BorderLayout, which divides the frame into five logical parts: North (up), South (down), East (right), West (left) and Center (everything in between). Components are centered by default.

You can create subframes for each part, and give them the a similar layout manager, or a completely different layout manager. in your case you'd want to create a new subframe at the South position of the main frame, and put your button in one of its North, Center or South positions.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

1) Create a JPanel usign a FlowLayout with "center alignment" and add your JButton to the panel.
2) Add this panel to the "SOUTH" of the content pane which uses a BorderLayout by default.

Answer (score 0):

i would take a look at LayoutManagers
BorderLayout would do the trick

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html